# Kentico Smart Search page crawler not working

Tags: search, indexing, kentico

[UPDATE] With the help of Kentico, I have determined the cause of the problem to be that the site could not be accessed within the web server itself.  Once I corrected that, the page crawler could index the content.

[ORIGINAL POST]
Problem with Kentico's Smart Search page crawler indexing.

The Smart Search page crawler indexing for our production site is not working.  Auto or manual rebuilds, it doesn't matter - it will run but we get no search results because nothing is being indexed.  However, it is working exactly as we expect on our development site.  Smart Search is configured exactly the same in both sites.  The content and all Kentico settings are exactly the same in both sites.  The web.config file is the same except for the database connection string.

When I run the page crawler in production, all the pages are crawled but none of the keywords are indexed.  I verified this using the Luke tool.  The index files are generated in the App_Data folder.

Other information:
Site is not running on Azure.
Event logs do not show any errors after rebuilding index.
We are using a Global Administrator account in the Crawler settings
The domain is provided in the Crawler settings.
I tried deleting the index files and rebuilding them, but there was no difference.
Analyzer type is Simple with Stemming.
No batch size is set.
Robots.txt is the same in both dev and prod.

Is there any configuration in IIS or something that might be preventing the page crawler indexer from working?  If it means anything, the dev site is not on the same machine or the same network as the production site.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the domain to localhost:80 in the Crawler settings?

Comment: I tried this, and the indexer didn't index any of the content.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the index directly on the production site? If not and you synced it from dev, then try configuring a new indexer on the production box. Also, check the production site at `Settings --> System --> Search --> Enable Smart Search Indexing`.

Comment: I went ahead and created a new indexer on the prod box, and confirmed that the Smart Search Indexing was enabled.  It's still not working.  The indexer does run, and the resulting Index Info indicates that the pages I wanted to be indexed were indexed, but somehow the keywords are not in the index.

Comment: Are other fields being indexed? If so, then it's probably the doctype. On your prod box, check `Page Types --> [YourPageType] --> Search Fields --> Keywords` to see if _Content_ and _Tokenized_ are checked. If not, then check them and rebuild the index.

Comment: Since I am using the Page Crawler indexer, the search fields are not used.    I have to use the Page Crawler index because most of the pages have content that are generated by web parts using datasources elsewhere in the content tree.  Anyway, I have found the problem and posted the fix in the original post.  Thanks again!